# How to debug a gulp task with VSCode

Tags: debugging, gulp, visual-studio-code

I need to debug a command `gulp start` with VScode (I got some mapping error with babel during transpilation that I don't understand yet...). The VSCode debug default configuration aims to launch `node app.js`. How to modify it to trigger the `gulp command`?

Here is the default configuration. If anyone has hint of how can I do that, I'll be in your debt :)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Lancer",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": null,
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attacher",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "address": "localhost",
            "restart": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In your "Lancer" configuration, make the following changes.

- Change *program* to **"${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js"**
- Change *args* to **["start"]**

Set a breakpoint in the task you want to debug and launch the debugger.  Change 'start' to the desired task name to debug other tasks.

Comment: if your gulpfile is not at root, but somewhere inside another folder, add property
"cwd": "${fileDirname}",
to your configuration